# @media print in SCSS doen't apply styles

Tags: javascript, html, sass

I add print functionality for one page in JavaScript, and everything work ok,except print styles.I also added a @Media print into my scss, but print page is without style. Can someone help me? :D

```
@media print {
  #printable-content {
    display: block !important;
    width: 79.17% !important;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    background-color: var(--color-main-gray) !important;
  }
}
```

I tried to change browsers, disable all extensions, but nothing happend.

Comment: It would be nice to have the HTML you are trying to target (more context). Maybe there is a typo on its `id`. The SCSS alone looks fine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.